# Jenkins Findbugs Empty output

Tags: java, jenkins, findbugs

I have configured jenkins to have a job which will run a batch command set to compile a java file.I have enabled findbugs for the job as well. But when I build the job the output i get is as follows

```
No changes.
Started by anonymous user
FindBugs: 0 warnings.

No warnings since build 4.
New zero warnings highscore: no warnings since yesterday!
During parsing an error has been reported.
```

When I click on error all I get is

```
Errors

No report files were found. Configuration error?
```

My job configuration looks like this 
[image]

If I run findbugs outside the jenkins I get the correct output

[image]

My Java File looks like this

```
class Input {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World! "); // Display the string.


    String str = null;
    if(str.equals("Test")) {
 /* The code here will not be reached, as an exception will be thrown. */
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The FindBugs Plugin searches for a *findbugs.xml* and generate a report. That means you have to run findbugs first.

> The FindBugs plug-in scans for findbugs.xml files in the build workspace and reports the number of warnings found. This plug-in is part of the suite of static code analysis plug-ins that are documented on a separate WIKI page.
>   ([source](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FindBugs+Plugin))

But you can run findbugs before manually ([more information](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/running.html#d0e465)):

```
java -jar $FINDBUGS_HOME/lib/findbugs.jar
```